# Asp.net mvc validation. How to specify several validation messages for one field in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have FormModel like this:

```
public class Model
{   
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to specify 2 different messages for RequiredAttribute and StringLengthAttribute. I don't want to specify my error messages in the validation attributes. I want to specify them in my view. But in my view I can do only something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, "validation error")
```

Anybody encountered this problem? 
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do that. It was intentionally left out by the MVC developers, as far as I recall because they figured it would lead to a cluttered UI. It also introduces the question "How would you like them to be output?

So you'd have to make your own helper method, which can easily be based on `ValidationMessageFor`, e.g. - to concatenate all the error messages separated by commas (untested, just for the concept):

```
public static class ValidationHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MultiValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(
       this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
       Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
       object htmlAttributes = null
       )
    {
        var propertyName = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(
                              expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).PropertyName;
        var modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState;

        if (modelState.ContainsKey(propertyName) && 
            modelState[propertyName].Errors.Count > 1)
        {
            // We have multiple error messages

            string messages = String.Join(", ", 
               modelState[propertyName].Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
            );

            // Reuse the built-in helper that takes a string as the message:
            return htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(
               expression, 
               messages, 
               htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? htmlAttributes
            );
        }

        // We only have a single message, so just call the standard helper
        return htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(
           expression, 
           null, 
           htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? htmlAttributes
        );
    }
}
```

Or you could do a complete validation message `<span>` for each (also untested):

```
// Only the multiple error case changes from the version above:

if (modelState.ContainsKey(propertyName) && 
   modelState[propertyName].Errors.Count > 1)
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   // Build a complete validation message for each message
   foreach (ModelError error in modelState[propertyName].Errors)
   {
      builder.Append(
         htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(
            expression, error.ErrorMessage, htmlAttributes
         )
      );
   }

   return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
}
```